# How to safely turn H2219 hints off?

Tags: delphi

How can I avoid H2219 hints being displayed?

> H2219: Private symbol '%s' declared but never used (Delphi)

I've created some methods that cause these hints, so the hints are legit. But I do not use any of these methods. I would like to **leave all compiler messages on**, since I think it is a good practice.

Any tip?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
{$HINTS OFF}
Fx: Integer;
{$HINTS ON}
```

Tested with Delphi DX10

Read more at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Hints_%28Delphi%29

Comment: Thank you! I've inserted the above directives in the interface part of my unit, just before/after a group of methods that I've declared + implemented but still never used

Answer (score 2):

Delete the unused methods. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). You say you're not using them. You're not even testing them. That means you have stale code sitting around, and stale code will drag you down.

When you later reach a point where you really need those methods, recover them from your revision-control system.

Comment: +! for this.  Solve the first problem.  Dead code is dead code.  Give it a proper funeral, don't just cover it up with dirt and call it "buried".

Comment: What about the situation if two projects are using the same class. In project A all methods of a class are used, in project B only some of the methods are used?

Comment: That denies the premise, @Wodzu. The question says they're *never* used. If they're used by one of two projects, then they're used. If your compiling the unit once and sharing the DCU file in two projects, then this message will never occur. If you're compiling it anew for each project, then use conditional compilation to exclude the unused stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the visibility of your methods from private to protected.

If this is a viable solution depends on why you want to have these unused methods around.

Answer (score 0):

@Rob Kennedy I disagree, in our case our developers build each project, and we don't share DCU (totally unrelated reason). In that case we could do conditional code, but that would be a lot of work. It is much simpler to just turn the hints off for the hand full of functions that are only used in the editor, while the viewer apps use the rest.

In a pure sense it does leave the hole open for truly dead code to live on. If I could retrofit the code base to use conditional copulation but that would introduce more risk than just suppressing the warning and potentially having some dead code slip through.